# Support of Radon Measure

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Here's a problem from homework:

Let $X$ be Locally Compact Hausdorff space (LCH), and let $\mu$ be a Radon measure on $X$. Define

$$\text{spt}(\mu) = \{ x \in X : \mu(N(x)) > 0 \, \text{for each open neighborhood} \, N(x) \}.$$
 Then show $\mu(\text{spt}^c) = 0$.

So my initial thought for a proof is the sort of obvious route:

Since $\text{spt}^c$ is the union of open sets, it is Borel, so we may use the inner regularity of $\mu$. Namely, let $K \subset \text{spt}^c$ be a compact set. Then, for each $x \in K$, there is $N(x)$ open so that $\mu(N(x)) = 0$. By compactness we can find a finite subcover and using subadditivity of an outer measure gives $\mu(K) = 0$ for every compact $K$. Then the supremum, which is the measure of $\text{spt}^c$ is also $0$, so we are done.

Though this doesn't use LCH or the finiteness on compact sets, so I must be doing something wrong.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the proof is fine. You don't need the LCH conditions nor the finiteness on compact sets for this statement, but the whole theory of Radon measures (duality/function spaces etc.) does need it ,so all those assumptions are commonly repeated between facts about them. Most books do not strive for maximal generality.

If generality is your cup of tea, check out Fremlin's encyclopaedic "Measury theory" (in 5 volumes, downloadable TeX files can be found on his website), where he does try to formulate the minimal conditions on $X$ and $\mu$ that make such statements true (in the topological measure theory part, where there are many notions of inner and outer regularity, equivalent in some but not all spaces etc.)

Comment: Regarding generality: separable metrizable implies second countable implies strongly Lindeloff implies the set $\text{spt}^c = \bigcup_{U \text{ open, } \mu(U)=0} U$ is actually a union of countably many open sets with $\mu$-measure zero, hence $\mu(\text{spt}^c) = 0$.

The two most common types of Borel measures encountered are Radon measures on LCH spaces (Haar measures on LCH groups are an important example) and Borel measures on separable metrizable spaces (probability measures on Polish spaces are an important example).